# pandas - set new index level for multiindex series

Tags: python, pandas, replace, multi-index

**I have a pandas series with MultiIndex and would like to replace one of the levels with the values in a seperate list**. I found a workaround how to achieve this, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way of doing this. This question also relates to the working of `set_levels()`, which I seemingly do not understand.

Here is my Series

```
>>> res
name     StringNum
A         2013         3203
          4135          579
          7881        30600
          7890          575
          9067        30600
          9233        30600
B         5378        30600
          7881        30600
C         5121        30600
...
N         9895         3935
U         1270        30600
          3049        30600
Length: 4213, dtype: float64
```

I have a list `RepNum`

```
>>> RepNum[:7]
['2013_x', '4135_y', '7881_x', '7890_x', '9067_z', '9233_w', '5378_y']
```

which values I would like to substitute for the index values of `StringNum`.
Right now I achieve this as follows

```
newres = pd.concat([res,pd.Series(res.index.get_level_values('name').tolist(),index=res.index),pd.Series(RepNum,index=res.index)],axis=1)
newres.set_index([1,2],inplace=True)
newres.index.names = ['name','StringNum']
>>> newres
                  0
name     StringNum            
A        2013_x   3203
         4135_y    579
         7881_x  30600
         7890_x    57
         9067_z  30600
         9233_w  30600
B        5378_y  30600
         7881_y  30600
C        5121_z  30600
...
```

which is what I want to get. I would have thought, though, that `res.index.set_levels([res.index.get_level_values('name').tolist(),RepNum],inplace=True)` would do the same in a more elegant and practical way, but the resulting series displays the wrong index values to the corresponding column entries

```
name     StringNum     
A        7890_x     3203
         9147_b      579
         5113_x    30600
         5134_v      575
         7289_w    30600
         9543_b    30600
         9895_y    30600
         5113_x    30600
         7003_v    30600
         9067_z      624
         7804_w    30600
...
```

You can also see that `name A` has much more entries now, than it actually has (`A` has only 6 entries in the original series). Btw, the same wrong result is obtained trying `res = pd.Series(res.values, index=NewIndex)`, where `NewIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([res.index.get_level_values('name').tolist(),RepNum], names=('name','number'))`. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: If you're running pandas `0.15.0` or higher does this work: `res.index.set_levels(RepNum, level=1, inplace=True)` I think the problem here is that you need to pair up the level values again so generate level 0 and level 1 index values, you could reset level index, rename and set it back again is a possibility

Comment: unfortunately I have to work with pandas 0.13.x. But you're right, `res.reset_index(level=1,inplace=True)`, `res['StringNum'] = RepNum` and then `res.set_index('StringNum',append=True)` does the same, and I prefer the look.

Comment: One correction to my own comment. I have to write `res = res.reset_index(level=1)`. The `inplace=True` does not work here, because apparently one cannot simply replace a Series with a DataFrame, which results by calling `reset_index`.